# How many arrangements of six books where two blue books must be next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

> There four black books and two blue books. How many ways are there of
>   arranging the six books in a line such that the two blue books must
>   be directly next to one another?

My book gives the following answer:

$$5 \times 2 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 $$

If I understand this correctly, we lump the two blue books together so that we are only considering the arrangement of $5$ different books, but we must multiply by $2$ since there are $2$ blue books, so there are $2!$ ways to arrange them. Does that sound correct? If there were $3$ blue books, would the answer be:

$$5 \times 3 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. There are 3! = 6 ways of arranging the blue books in your second example, so the answer would be $$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 720.$$

We can state it generally as:

> There $k$ black books and $m$ blue books. How many ways are there of
>   arranging the $k+m$ books in a line such that the $m$ blue books must
>   all be directly next to one another?

Glue all of $m$ blue books together so there are effectively $k+1$ things to arrange, and we know that there are $(k+1)!$ ways to do that. We must, however, have this for each of the $m!$ ways there are to arrange the $m$ blue books. Therefore, our answer is $(k+1)! \  m!$.